# Prove that the legrende $(\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{(p+5)(p-1)}{8}}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p>2$, where $p$ is prime . $$\text{Prove:} \ \ (\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{(p+5)(p-1)}{8}}$$

$$\ \ (\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})(\frac{2}{p})=(\frac{p-1}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})$$

So we have

$$\ \ (\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p}) \times(-1)^\frac{p^2-1}{8}=(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}$$

$$\ \ (\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})=(-1)^\frac{(4-p)(p-3)}{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

From [Legendre Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html) identity from prime $p$, $$\left(\frac{ab}p\right)=\left(\frac  ap\right)\left(\frac bp\right)$$

Here $\displaystyle a=2,b=\frac{p-1}2\implies ab=p-1\equiv-1\pmod p$

Check when $-1,2$ are [Quadratic Residues](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html) of prime $p$

Comment: I am working out the problem and I am getting the exponent $\frac{(4-p)(p-3)}{8}$. What am I doing wrong? I am showing my work above?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown,  $$(-1)^\frac{p-1}2/(-1)^\frac{p^2-1}8$$  $$=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2-\frac{p^2-1}8}=(-1)^{-\frac{p^2-4p+3}8}$$

Now, $$-(p^2-4p+3)+(p+5)(p-1)=8(p-1)$$  $$\implies-\frac{p^2-4p+3}8+\frac{(p+5)(p-1)}8=p-1$$ which is even

$$\implies-\frac{p^2-4p+3}8, -\frac{(p+5)(p-1)}8$$ have same parity

So, $$(-1)^{-\frac{p^2-4p+3}8}, (-1)^{-\frac{(p+5)(p-1)}8}$$ are same

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv2^{-1}(p-1)\mod{p} $$